# Replicating Hubspots drag and drop form builder UI with jQuery UI Sortable and Bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

Hubspot have a nice drag and drop form builder UI (see exaple gif below) which I am trying to replicate using Bootstrap 4 grid and [jQuery UI sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

My main issue is that jQuery sortable is quite literal so my "dividers" get moved around with the user dragging interaction. Ideally, my deviders would act as drop zones much like Hubspot does.

**Hubspot example**

[image: Hubspot example]

**Current recreation**

[image: Current recreation]

- `gray` = Empty divider. Would love these to be drop zones.
- `red` = Bootstrap row (`.row`)
- `blue` = Bootstrap column (`.col`)
- `pink` = Column content.

See my current recreation here: https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/4wrn0tq1/1/

My question to you... Can you help guide me to an improved implementation? Or perhaps there an alternative solution? Doesn't have to be jQuery or Bootstrap.

Any advise would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally forgot about the [Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) so I've sacked of jQuery UI sortable and been able to create the desired result.

Most notably these events...

```
$stage.on( 'dragstart', '.handle', function( event ) {
    // ...
} );

$stage.on( 'dragend', '.handle', function( event ) {
    // ...
} );

$stage.on( 'dragenter', '.row:empty, .col:empty', function( event ) {
    // ...
} );

$stage.on( 'dragover', '.row:empty, .col:empty', function( event ) {
    // ...
} );

$stage.on( 'dragleave', '.row:empty, .col:empty', function( event ) {
    // ...
} );
```

Please see the updated example here: https://jsfiddle.net/thelevicole/4wrn0tq1/2/

It's definitely not ready for production but might be helpful to someone looking for a functionality.

And here's a gif of it for reference...

[image: Updated example]

---

**Update**

For anyone interested I am turning the core of this into a jQuery plugin. You can see it over on [GitHub here](https://github.com/thelevicole/ui-layouter). A working example of the plugin in it's current state can be viewed here: https://thelevicole.com/ui-layouter/